# Parallelising nested do loop Fortran

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I don't get any speedup when I try to do the following in the subroutine:

```
!$ call omp_set_num_threads(threadno)
call system_clock(x1)

!$OMP PARALLEL do private(i), reduction(+:total)    
    do i = 1,m
        total = 0.d0
        call result(a,l,b,qm,q,en) !here l is input for subroutine and en is output
        qm(:,i) = q
        qtv(i) = qt
        mean = sum(q)/size(q)
        do i2 = 1,k
            total = total + ((mean-q(i2))**2)/(a+b)
        end do
        qvv(i1) = total
    end do
    call system_clock(x2)
    print *, x2-x1
!$OMP END PARALLEL do
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, m is set as an input in the subroutine. I used cpu_time to time and thread is set as an input.

Comment: If you have 20 threads, and it runs 20x faster in wall clock time, then what do you expect the CPU_TIME to be? 1/20 or the same CPU time?

Comment: @Holmz 1/20 of the time?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I've used system_clock for the wall time.

Comment: The sum of 20 cores running 1/20 of the time should give a CPU_TIME of 1, just like the non parallel. Usually more. Howeevr the wall time should ideally be 1/20. This should be blindingly fast, so you may need to call it a bunch to get some decent statistics.

Comment: @Holmz So how can I make it so that parallelising speeds up my code because at the moment, for some reason, as the number of threads increase, the wall time doesn't really change.

Comment: Well you need to look at both CPU and wall time. @HighPerformanceMark mentioned omp_time . There are a variety of things that slow down code, most often shuffling memory in and out of the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Comments on the OpenMP part:

1. `total` should not be reset in the loop but before the `!$OMP` clause.
2. `i2` and `mean` should be private.
3. If `q` does not change between iterations of the loop, `sum(q)/size(q)` should be placed outside.

The lack of private setting can lead to memory access conflicts (and thus slowdowns).

I guess that the code you show is close to but not really the one that you compile. It would be useful to have a compiled code to provide a better help.

Cheers,

Pierre

EDIT: for timing OpenMP code, you should use `omp_get_wtime` (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fget_005fwtime.html) that gives the walltime https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time. The module for openmp routines is loaded with `use omp_lib`

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for the help. I've amended my  code and hope that it helps. q does change between iterations of thel oop as I'm calling the subroutine results, which itself has a randomising element.

Comment: Do I still need to have i1 as private? Why can't I reset ttoal after the OMP clause/after the loop? I want to initialise total for each time it iterates

Comment: only the loop variable directly following the `!$OMP DO` clause is private by default.
I don't see how `i2` enters the game but unless it is defined *before* the loop and not changed in the loop, it should be private.
As `en` and `q` are output by the routine, they should be private too.

Comment: About `total`, you set it as a *reduction* variable, with operation `+`. This means that its value will be the sum of all the values obtained in the loop.
But the reduction clause does not imply that you do not need to do `total = total + loop_variable_to_add` in the loop. The loop should be correct if the `!$OMP` clause is not active (i.e. code compiled with no openmp support).

Comment: What do you mean by this part "But the reduction clause does not imply that you do not need to do total = total + loop_variable_to_add in the loop."?

Comment: It means that your code should work also with no openmp. As the variable name is "total", it matches the following idea (hence my comment):`total=0; do i=1, n ; total = total + x(i) ; end do`. The line `total = total + ...` is also needed when you do openmp. If your variable `total` is not actually used this way, the reduction clause should not be used.

Comment: I tried the above and found no speedup -- would it be because of the fact that my laptop is dual core and I'm running the code on a Virtual Machine?

Comment: You must check that the virtual machine has access to the two cores. You can set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to 1 and 2 to compare the result then.

Comment: Oh, do you actually care for the value of `total` after the loop on `i2` has ended? If not, `total` should be set private and not with a reduction clause.

Comment: Afther the loop on i2 has ended, I will have each of the values of total for the iterations stored in the vector qvv. That is the extent.

Comment: I set total to private as suggested and had a speedup of about 1.31. Is that reasonable?

Comment: This depends on the number of iterations of the loop and the time it takes to perform one iteration.
There is a minimal amount of time to create the OpenMP threads that ideally should be small compared to the time taken for the computation. This is platform/os/etc dependent.

Comment: Hi Pierre, I was wondering whether when trying to use a Python module that uses subroutines from Fortran which utilise OpenMP, whether I need to include some sort of -fopenmp marker when compiling with  f2py?

Comment: Never tried, googling gave this: https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Dynetrekk/f2py_OpenMP_draft.html
There is an option to the setup.py file `extra_compile_args = ['-fopenmp']`

Comment: current doc: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/distutils.html#module-numpy.distutils